# css positioning problem with hover pseudo class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to design a simple page for practicing with just html and css. I used a hover pseudo class for the croissant image. It works but when I hover the mouse over the croissant the coffee cup image will move to right a little(almost 50 or 100 pixels) and when I hover off of the croissant the coffee cup will back in its position before.
meanwhile I'm new in web design and just start learning few days.
here's my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-image: url('https://c8.alamy.com/comp/2BT68F1/vector-black-chalkboard-style-hand-drawn-bakery-horizontal-border-pattern-suitable-for-bread-packaging-cafe-menu-design-and-wallpaper-2BT68F1.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

#img1 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
}

#instagram1 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
}

#instagram2 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  right: 168px;
  top: 5px;
}

#bakery {
  color: black;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 5px;
}

#cafe {
  color: black;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  right: 75px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 550px;
  background-color: #b3d9ff;
}

#croissant {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: 1100px;
  top: 250px;
}

#espresso {
  position: relative;
  top: 280px;
  right: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

#croissant:hover {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<img id="croissant" src="https://freepngimg.com/thumb/croissant/29021-7-croissant-transparent-background.png">

<img id="espresso" src="https://services.garmin.com/appsLibraryBusinessServices_v0/rest/apps/eae8653c-e809-4e35-ac17-d9866ba92b26/icon/e684d982-4aa3-48fb-8e2e-08d53e5096b6">

<div>
  <img id="instagram1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Instagram_logo_2016.svg/768px-Instagram_logo_2016.svg.png">

  <p id="bakery"> @red.bakery </p>
  </br>
  </br>
  <img id="instagram2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Instagram_logo_2016.svg/768px-Instagram_logo_2016.svg.png">

  <p id="cafe"> @red.cafe </p>
</div>
```

Comment: First thing : `width:250` and `height:250` are not correct. Additionally, as you're changing the width of something on hover, I'm not fully surprised some other elements shift a bit...

Comment: as you are changing croissant height and width on hover, it will definitely make other elements shift accordingly. What you can do is, wrap the croissant in a span and make croissant's position absolute and span position relative and then try again.

Comment: @LaurentS. why width and height in 250 are incorrect? would you explain?

Comment: @MuhammadZaib and why other elements shift when I change one element position or size? I mean I want to know the basis and structure of this problem.

Comment: You need to specify a unit. There's no default unit so not specifying one is invalid CSS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In details:

1. [relative](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/#relative)
   ...
   if you do give it some other positioning attribute, say, top: 10px;, it will shift its position 10 pixels down from where it would normally be.
   ...
2. [absolute](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/#absolute)
   ...
   use the positioning attributes top, left, bottom, and right to set the location. Remember that these values will be relative to the next parent element with relative (or absolute) positioning. If there is no such parent, it will default all the way back up to the  element itself meaning it will be placed relative to the page itself
   ...

[Muhammad Zaib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4793177/muhammad-zaib) has the answer, and there is a demo:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-image: url('https://c8.alamy.com/comp/2BT68F1/vector-black-chalkboard-style-hand-drawn-bakery-horizontal-border-pattern-suitable-for-bread-packaging-cafe-menu-design-and-wallpaper-2BT68F1.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

#img1 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
}

#instagram1 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
}

#instagram2 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  right: 168px;
  top: 5px;
}

#bakery {
  color: black;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 5px;
}

#cafe {
  color: black;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  right: 75px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 550px;
  background-color: #b3d9ff;
}

#croissant-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: 1100px;
  top: 250px;
}

#croissant {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

#croissant:hover {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
}

#espresso {
  position: relative;
  top: 280px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<span id="croissant-wrapper">
    <img id="croissant" src="https://freepngimg.com/thumb/croissant/29021-7-croissant-transparent-background.png">
</span>

<img id="espresso" src="https://services.garmin.com/appsLibraryBusinessServices_v0/rest/apps/eae8653c-e809-4e35-ac17-d9866ba92b26/icon/e684d982-4aa3-48fb-8e2e-08d53e5096b6">

<div>
  <img id="instagram1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Instagram_logo_2016.svg/768px-Instagram_logo_2016.svg.png">

  <p id="bakery"> @red.bakery </p>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <img id="instagram2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Instagram_logo_2016.svg/768px-Instagram_logo_2016.svg.png">

  <p id="cafe"> @red.cafe </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You should explain it!

Comment: would you explain about the type of positions? I mean why the croissant's position is absolute and the croissant-wrapper's position is relative?

Comment: The answer is updated. In this case, the parent `croissant-wrapper` allow `croissant` to work with `position: absolute`.